# How do I call router in service files quasar vue

Tags: vue.js, router, quasar

I need to print router in my service file. How do I do that?

I have below folder structure in my quasar vue

```
src
  service
   index.js // I need to call router here
  src 
  pages
  components
  router
```

Here is my router file routes.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('pages/Login.vue'),
  }
 ]


if (process.env.MODE !== 'ssr') {
  routes.push({
    path: '*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  })
}

export default routes
```

Here is my code from router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default function ({ }) {
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  })
  Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const accessToken = Cookies.getItem('token')
    if (accessToken === null && to.name !== 'Login') {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        replace: true
      })
      return
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })

  return Router
}
```

In service/index.js, I have tried to print `router` and `this.$router`, both of them are not working. Is there anything I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Vue Router outside Vue Components, you must import `router/index.js`.

First you must change the content of `router/index.js` for store the VueRouter instance.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
let router = null;

export default function() {
  if (!router) {
    router = new VueRouter({
      scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
      routes,
      mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
      base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE,
    });

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      const accessToken = Cookies.getItem('token');
      if (accessToken === null && to.name !== 'Login') {
        next({ path: '/login', replace: true });
        return;
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  }

  return router;
}
```

Now you can use VueRouter outside Vue Components:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="test">TEST</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import push from "@/service/index.js";

export default {
  methods: {
    test() {
      push();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```js
// service/index.js

import router from '@/router/index.js';

export default function() {
  router().push({ name: 'About' });
}
```

Comment: I need to use router.app as well, but there is ntg under this variable

Comment: Try to execute `router().app` in file `service/index.js`.  Because in `router/index.js` you expose a function.

Comment: I have tried, it gives `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure undefined`

Comment: Please post the code of `service/index.js`. Probably you have a async function that return a promise.